# To what place (does/do) either the man or his sons wish to go?

Tags: grammatical-number, conjunctions, verb-agreement, subject-verb-inversion

I have a problem with this situation. Would you mind helping me?

To what place (does/do) either the man or his sons wish to go?

Can you show me which is correct? do or does is correct?

Comment: The standard grammatical advice is that if you have an *or*, the verb agrees with the noun closest to it. So it would be *... does either the man or his sons*, and it would be *... do either the brothers or their father*.

Comment: There must be a duplicate question somewhere here, but I haven't been able to locate one with a good answer.